# How to find which properties in the .theme file are used to generate a given CSS class in GXT3?

Tags: css, gwt, extjs, themes, gxt

Current Sencha documentation about their Theme Builder is very limited, it covers only the file basic structure and the syntax (including gradients and functions):

http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/ui/theme/syntax/ThemeBuilderSyntax.html

My problem is which property should I set in the .theme file in order to affect an specific CSS class? For example the font used in the header of a ContentPanel.

First thing I tried was to have a look in the file themebuilder\examples\skeleton-config\skeleton-config.theme which is supposed to have "all required properties", but I could not find any "contentPanel" in it.

This is the example they have in the documentation:

```
details {
  info {
    messageText = defaultFont
    //note that this could also be written as
    //messageText = theme.defaultFont
  }
}
```

In this case it is straightforward because there is an Info class which matches the "info" element used in the theme.

Then I had a look in the generated HTML and found this CSS class name in the header of my ContentPanel:

.CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText

By looking at this class name I thought the element name to be used in the .theme file would be "panel" and the property name would be "headerText", but unfortunately checking the file skeleton-config.theme I saw there is no headerText property in the panel element.

I have found headerText in other elements like datePicker, errortip, info and tip, so it is funny that panel does not have it.

Comment: In order to see the generated CSS class name you will need to set this property in your .gwt.xml file:  <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty" />

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found to know exactly which configuration parameter I have to set in order to affect an specific CSS was to have a look at the GWT generated classes.

I started by checking the generated HTML and there I found the CSS class name:

```
.CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText
```

Then I searched for this string in the directory target/.generated (I am using Maven) and found the class Css3HeaderAppearance_Css3HeaderResources_default_InlineClientBundleGenerator.java where that string appeared many times:

```
".CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText {\n  right : " + ("20px")  + ";\n}\n" +
".CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText {\n  font-family : " + ("tahoma"+ ","+ " " +"arial"+ ","+ " " +"verdana"+ ","+ " " +"sans-serif")  + ";\n  font-size : " + ("11px")  + ";\n  font-weight : " + ("bold")  + ";\n  line-height : " + ("15px")  + ";\n  color : ") + ((theme().panel().font().color() + "")  + ";\n  font-size : " + (theme().panel().font().size() + "")  + ";\n  font-weight : " + (theme().panel().font().weight() + "")  + ";\n  font-family : " + (theme().panel().font().family() + "")  + ";\n  line-height : " + ("15px")  + ";\n  text-transform : " + ("none")  + ";\n}\n.PR-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerBar {\n  float : " + ("left")  + ";\n}\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n")) : ((".OR-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-header {\n  padding : " + ("4px"+ " " +"3px"+ " " +"2px"+ " " +"5px")  + ";\n  position : " + ("relative")  + ";\n  padding : " + ("0")  + ";\n}\n.BS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerIcon {\n  float : " + ("left")  + ";\n}\n.AS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerHasIcon .BS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerIcon {\n  width : " + ("18px")  + ";\n}\n.AS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerHasIcon " +
".CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText {\n  left : " + ("20px")  + ";\n}\n" +
".CS-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerText {\n  font-family : " + ("tahoma"+ ","+ " " +"arial"+ ","+ " " +"verdana"+ ","+ " " +
"sans-serif")  + ";\n  font-size : " + ("11px")  + ";\n  font-weight : " + ("bold")  + ";\n  line-height : " + ("15px")  +
";\n  color : ") + ((theme().panel().font().color() + "")  + ";\n  font-size : " + (theme().panel().font().size() + "")  + ";\n  " +
"font-weight : " + (theme().panel().font().weight() + "")  + ";\n  font-family : " + (theme().panel().font().family() + "")  + ";\n  line-height : " + ("15px")  + ";\n  text-transform : " + ("none")  + ";\n}\n.PR-com-example-client-base-panel-Css3HeaderAppearance-Css3HeaderStyle-headerBar {\n  float : " + ("right")  + ";\n}\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n/* CssDef */\n"));
```

I have noticed that it first generates some hard-coded CSS classes and at the end it generated a CSS class based on the values returned by calls to theme().*.

Finally, by comparing these calls with the structure of the file skeleton-config.theme I had the answer to my question:

theme() maps to the "details" element in the .theme file

theme().panel() maps to details.panel or

```
details {
    panel {
```

so the configuration I had to use was the font property inside the panel element.

This answers my first question, but it does not clarify what are all widgets affected by the "panel" element in the .theme file.

Comment: That way certainly works, though you can go even easier by looking in the ContentPanel appearance impl's .css files and see theme.panel.font.color... etc. The details interfaces (in this case PanelDetails) describe the theme details file, and are then accessed as they are needed from the css files and appearances. The guides are a little light on the specifics of what each property does, but check the skeleton-config.theme file for better descriptions. Let me know if you'd like me to write up a fuller answer on any of this.

Comment: I see, so each appearance will have a Css3 implementation and in the case of ContentPanel it is the Css3ContentPanelAppearance. Looking at this class I found the getHeaderAppearance method which returns Css3HeaderAppearance which in turn has the reference to the Css3Header.css file that has the property I was searching for.

Comment: Finally, by searching for all usages of HeaderAppearance I can have an idea of all widgets that would be affected by that configuration.

Comment: Yeah - the main goal when we built the config was to keep the set of properties to a minimum, and avoid massive webs of interdependencies. The other route is essentially 'write your own css', or 'start with our css and add more', and that seems to have been rejected, unless we go the classic (and very not-gwt) way of just having a css file thousands of lines long... We need an idea or visual editors, but wanted to be sure we got the rest of the system right first. So far, so good we think...